# Cross over analysis in R. Reduce a dataframe to sum of combinations across features

Tags: r

Better worded title suggestions welcome.

I am attempting to some overlap/cross over analysis among some data. Suppose I have a data frame of the following format:

```
bla <- data.frame(
  a = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0),
  b = c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0),
  c = c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)
)
```

For each combination of a, b and c, I would like the sum of cases.

I tried playing around with expand grid:

```
combinations <- expand.grid(names(bla))
```

But that just returned a,b,c whereas I was hoping for a, ab, abc, b, bc, etc. Not sure how to achieve that?

Even then, if I did manage to get all possible combinations of the data frame headers a, b and c, what then?

Example, combination a and c is true 3 times (1st, 3rd and 7th rows) so I'm looking for a object where ac = 3.

How can I reduce bla to get the count of cases, including overlap along each feature?

Comment: `table(bla)` perhaps? Or `as.data.frame(table(bla))` if you prefer.

Comment: Aha! Yes, I should have known that already. I felt like this was more straight forwards than I was making it look :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also a nice function for this in the package `limma`:

```
vennCounts(bla)

  a b c Counts
1 0 0 0      1
2 0 0 1      0
3 0 1 0      1
4 0 1 1      2
5 1 0 0      2
6 1 0 1      3
7 1 1 0      1
8 1 1 1      0
```

And you can even visualize it as a Venn diagram:

```
vennDiagram(bla)
```

[image]